# Delete Lists with Mailchimp.NET

Tags: .net, mailchimp

I'm using the following:

https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET

However I don't see a way to DELETE a list.  I don't want to go through and delete hundreds of emails individually - I want to totally obliterate a list and then create a new one.

How can I delete a MailChimp list from .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the library you're using is for the deprecated v2.0 MailChimp API. There doesn't seem to be a [Delete List](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/unsubscribe.php) endpoint available in the 2.0 endpoints. However, in the readme of the library you've linked to, there's a link to a [v3.0 wrapper](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net) which could have that feature. V3.0 of the MailChimp API has a [Delete List endpoint](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#%20) so unless you want upgrade to that endpoint, you may need to manually unsubscribe.

Comment: Thanks for this, though that library is terrible.  It forces you to use async and the documentation is inconsistent with the behavior.

Comment: @RobVious - Ah I see, I'm not familiar with it or the MailChimp API. You could potentially just call the Delete List endpoint in v3.0 manually and use your existing wrapper for everything else.

Comment: Thanks - do you know I can do that from .NET?  A bit new to this api, how to configure headers for it, etc.

Comment: There are various ways depending how much of it you want to do manually. [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) is quite a popular library and saves a lot of the headache or see [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp) as an example of creating your own class. Generally speaking, you'd want to stay consistent with the API version you're using so, ideally if possible, you may want to use only the v3.0 API but that's a design decision.